# ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement using FlyWay

Tags: oracle, flyway

I get this error 
""2013-05-20 15:44:28,637 ERROR [Server Startup] apachecommons.ApacheCommonsLog (ApacheCommonsLog.java:51) - com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: **Error executing statement at line 6:   function bitor(p1 number, p2 number) return number**
""2013-05-20 15:44:29,093 ERROR [Server Startup] apachecommons.ApacheCommonsLog (ApacheCommonsLog.java:51) - Caused by java.sql.SQLException: **ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement**

My .sql file is

```
create or replace

package pkg_file_classification is
  procedure updateServerInnerFilesClass(in_server_id number);
  function bitor(p1 number, p2 number) return number;
end pkg_file_classification;
```

Comment: Definitely a bug in the parser. Please file an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just removed empty line and it passed

```
create or replace package pkg_file_classification is
  procedure updateServerInnerFilesClass(in_server_id number);
  function bitor(p1 number, p2 number) return number;
end pkg_file_classification;
```